# Can NSOpenPanel's 'urls' variable be empty?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsopenpanel

I am displaying an NSOpenPanel in my app as follows:

```
let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    openPanel.beginSheetModal(for: self.window!, completionHandler: { returnCode in
        if returnCode == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
            let chosenItems = openPanel.urls
            if chosenItems.isEmpty { return }
            else { self.startSlideshow(rootURLS: chosenItems) }
        }
    })
```

I was wondering if `openPanel.urls` can ever be empty / if I should implement a sheet for an error message and all, or if I can assume it to always contain some value. I've tried simply selecting nothing in the panel. As a result, `openPanel.urls` simply contained the directory the panel showed, which is why I figured it might never be empty. Also I did realize that the panel's 'Open' button is deactivated sometimes, presumably when no urls would be returned (?).

I was hoping someone here has more experience with this and might be able to tell me wether that is actually the case or I am horribly wrong here.

Comment: The dialog pretty much ensures that, if you get an `OK` response, that the `urls` property will contain the selection. The "Open" button is disabled whenever there isn't a valid selection, QED. (You're getting an URL when nothing is selected because you enabled `canChooseDirectories`.)

Comment: OTOH - any decent code checks for expected data and errors for robustness, so checking whether the `url` is empty cannot harm..